# Rails - Maximum Use of Symbols in Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have just stumbled upon a thinking block and wanted to have an input from the pros.

I am using Rails and here is a sample code from my views:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: confirmation_path(resource_name), html: { id: "confirmation", method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Resend confirmation instructions", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I think I can replace all the strings with symbols which would be memory efficient like so:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: confirmation_path(resource_name), html: { id: :confirmation, method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: :'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Resend confirmation instructions", class: { :btn, :'btn-primary' } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Is my assumption correct? The boundary between using symbols and strings is quite a thin one so how does one decide what to use where or should one always use symbols? Should code readability also be a factor?

Comment: In this case, I think code readability should be your overriding concern. This sounds very much like premature (and dubious) optimization. Strings make a lot more sense to me in this situation.

Comment: I agree that the optimisation is dubious: the performance improvement you will get from this will lie somewhere between zero and negligible, and in the process you will make your code hard to read, and therefore more likely to get broken.

Answer (score 0):

On a long run you might not want to follow this way,.

As rails always has some memory concerns,

> Symbol.all_symbols.count

Will fairly give some idea how many are initialized already, why do you want to add up a few more, use strings as they are mutable.

In worst case if user sent params are converted to symbol you might be in big trouble, which will lead to DOS([Denial of Service](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/denial_of_service/))

Just for very very minor difference, you may be paying more later on.

On for Ruby 2.2, there is an incremental GC, which will be better solution for this.

At times our application seems to running **memory > 90%**, which is been a problem at times. Do safeguard from from beginning, later you don't need to crack.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would not necessarily be beneficial; the downside to symbols is that they're never collected. In this case you'd be making some rather large symbols, (slightly) lowering the readability of your code, and permanently committing displayed text to memory. My rule tends to be use symbols for references to any value on which I operate, but use string literals for anything I'm displaying to the user (unless I use it as a symbol as well, like in the case of field names on forms).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not creating new symbols (eg `String#to_sym`), you should only focus on code readability, which based on convention [example](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) is improved when using symbols.